# Replace <button> with Font Awesome icon

Tags: html, css

I want to replace a button with a Font Awesome icon in css, but I can't hide the text of the button.

```
button {
    border: medium none;
    bottom: 0;
    font-size: 35px;
    left: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 0;
    background-color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
button::before {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    content:"";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/evhqz1rh/2/

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really must do this with CSS only (as opposed to just removing "menu" from your HTML), you can set the `overflow: visible` but position the element off the screen, then adjust the `:before` pseudo class to move its contents back onto the screen.

```
#primary-navigation-menu-toggle {
    border: medium none;
    bottom: 0;
    font-size: 35px;
    left: auto;
    overflow: visible;   /* change to visible */
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 0;
    background-color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    right: -500px;       /* position off the page */
}
#primary-navigation-menu-toggle::before {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    content:"";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    position: absolute;
    left: -470px;        /* position on the page */
}
```

See it on this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/evhqz1rh/3/).

Comment: But now you can't click the button any more?!

Comment: The alert isn't shown when I click the bars. Is it because I use Firefox (latest stable version: 41.0.2)? Also, the mouse pointer is not a hand, but a arrow.

Comment: I tested the latest jsfiddle in different browsers. Firefox - not working, pointer - arrow; IE and Edge - working, pointer - hand.

Comment: I'm now using your solution, but I changed the `button` element to an `a` element. Now it's working in IE and FF.

http://jsfiddle.net/evhqz1rh/6/

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use a `button` element to do this. A simple `span` or `div` would do as both support the `onClick` event.

Another option is to simply remove the "Menu" text from your button code:

```
<button aria-expanded="false" id="primary-navigation-menu-toggle"></button>
```

Comment: Maybe it's better to use JS to display the button, because I also use the `onClick` event with JS.